# I want to call the file upload API using vaadin-upload

Tags: vaadin, lit

I'm trying to implement a file upload function using "vaadin-upload".
I have a locally built file upload server implemented with Spring boot, and I want to use its API to upload files.
I want to use this API to upload files input from "vaadin-upload".

The API specification is this.

- [URL] http://localhost:8080/uploadFile
- [HEADER] Content-Type: multipart/form-data
- [requestparam] file: multipart file

The API reference for "[vaadin-upload](https://cdn.vaadin.com/vaadin-web-components/20.0.3/#/elements/vaadin-upload)" does not tell me how to execute the API. I don't know how to run the API.
Please tell me.

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="ja">
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
<title>sample</title>
<script type="module" src="./out/api-sample/file-upload.js"></script>

<file-upload></file-upload>
```

file-upload.ts

```
import {customElement} from 'lit/decorators.js';
import {html, LitElement} from 'lit';
import '@vaadin/vaadin-upload';

@customElement('file-upload')
export class FileUpload extends LitElement {
  render() {
    return html`
      <vaadin-upload></vaadin-upload>
      <vaadin-button @click="${this.upload}">upload</vaadin-button>
    `;
  }

  upload() {
    // ???
  }
}

declare global {
  interface HTMLElementTagNameMap {
    'file-upload': FileUpload;
  }
}
```

FileController.java

```
package com.example.demo.controller;

import com.example.demo.date.UploadFileResponse;
import com.example.demo.service.FileStorageService;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.support.ServletUriComponentsBuilder;

@RestController
public class FileController {

    private final FileStorageService fileStorageService;

    @Autowired
    public FileController(FileStorageService fileStorageService) {
        this.fileStorageService = fileStorageService;
    }

    @PostMapping("/uploadFile")
    public UploadFileResponse uploadFile(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file) {
        String fileName = fileStorageService.storeFile(file);

        String fileDownloadUri = ServletUriComponentsBuilder.fromCurrentContextPath()
                .path("/downloadFile/")
                .path(fileName)
                .toUriString();

        return new UploadFileResponse(fileName, fileDownloadUri, file.getContentType(), file.getSize());
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can configure the upload request by setting the respective attributes on the Upload component, for example:

```html
<vaadin-upload 
  target="http://localhost:8080/uploadFile"
  headers='{"Content-Type": "multipart/form-data"}'
  form-data-name="file"
></vaadin-upload>
```

Not 100% sure about `form-data-name`, but looking at the component's sources it should do what you want.

Upload already contains a button, so you don't need to add your own button to trigger the upload. If you still want to trigger the upload programmatically for some reason, you can use [Upload.uploadFiles](https://cdn.vaadin.com/vaadin-web-components/22.0.0-alpha10/#/elements/vaadin-upload#method-uploadFiles).

Reference: [Upload documentation](https://vaadin.com/docs/latest/ds/components/upload/#handling-upload-requests-web-component-only), [Upload API docs](https://cdn.vaadin.com/vaadin-web-components/22.0.0-alpha10/#/elements/vaadin-upload)